# making table in itextsharp pdf

Tags: c#, itext

i am creating a pdf which contain a `header` and `footer` section,
in my body section, i want a table which contain my `datagridview` data. pdf may longer then 3 or 4 page. i have made it, but the problem is that, my table is showing 2 times in a page. you can see in capture which is given bellow.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qpHt.png)

my code is

```
public partial class Footer : PdfPageEventHelper
    {
        iTextSharp.text.Image image;


        public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document doc1)
        {
            Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 30f, 30f, 42f, 30f);
            doc.Open();
            iTextSharp.text.Image footer = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance("dslmfooter.png");
            footer.ScaleAbsoluteHeight(40f);
            footer.ScaleAbsoluteWidth(520f);
            doc.Add(footer);
            footer.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
            PdfPTable footerTbl = new PdfPTable(1);
            footerTbl.TotalWidth = 300;
            footerTbl.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(footer);
            cell.Border = 0;
            cell.PaddingLeft = 10;
            footerTbl.AddCell(cell);
            footerTbl.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 25, 50, writer.DirectContent);
        }
    }

    public partial class Header : PdfPageEventHelper
    {
        iTextSharp.text.Image image;


        public override void OnStartPage(PdfWriter writer, Document doc1)
        {




            var color_table = new BaseColor(0, 0, 128);
            BaseFont Kalpurush = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1250, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
            iTextSharp.text.Font f_12_normal = new iTextSharp.text.Font(Kalpurush, 11, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL);
            iTextSharp.text.Font f_12_color = new iTextSharp.text.Font(Kalpurush, 12, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, color_table);
            Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 30f, 30f, 42f, 30f);
            doc.Open();
            iTextSharp.text.Image Header = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance("dslmheader.png");
            Header.ScaleAbsoluteHeight(170f);
            Header.ScaleAbsoluteWidth(550f);
            doc.Add(Header);
            Header.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
            PdfPTable footerTb2 = new PdfPTable(1);
            footerTb2.TotalWidth = 300;
            footerTb2.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
            PdfPCell cell1 = new PdfPCell(Header);
            cell1.Border = 0;
            cell1.PaddingLeft = 10;
            footerTb2.AddCell(cell1);
            footerTb2.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 10, 830, writer.DirectContent);




        }
    }



    private void print_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(@"server=" + _str1[0] + ";username=" + _str1[1] + ";password=" + _str1[2] + ";database=" + _str1[3]);
        MySqlCommand cmd;
        DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
        MySqlDataReader reader;
        string str = "";
        string order = "";
        ///checking////
        int dq = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < dgv_party_rod.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            row = dgv_party_rod.Rows[i];
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[0].Value) == true)
            {
                dq++;
                str = row.Cells["item"].Value.ToString();
                order = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["order_no"].Value);
            }
        }

        if (dq > 0)
        {
            /////////////////itextsharp///////////////////
            Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 30f, 30f, 42f, 30f);
            // BaseFont sm = GetFont("Kalpurush"); 
            var FontColour = new BaseColor(0, 74, 121);
            var colour = new BaseColor(0, 122, 204);
            var colour1 = new BaseColor(232, 17, 35);
            var color_table = new BaseColor(0, 0, 128);
            var color_green = new BaseColor(29, 163, 98);
            BaseFont Kalpurush = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1250, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
            iTextSharp.text.Font f_15_bold = new iTextSharp.text.Font(Kalpurush, 15, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD);
            iTextSharp.text.Font f_15_normal = new iTextSharp.text.Font(Kalpurush, 15, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL);
            iTextSharp.text.Font f_12_normal = new iTextSharp.text.Font(Kalpurush, 11, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL);
            iTextSharp.text.Font f_12_color = new iTextSharp.text.Font(Kalpurush, 12, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, color_table);
            iTextSharp.text.Font f_16_normal = new iTextSharp.text.Font(Kalpurush, 16, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL);
            iTextSharp.text.Font f_16_bold = new iTextSharp.text.Font(Kalpurush, 16, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD, colour1);
            iTextSharp.text.Font f_16_bold_green = new iTextSharp.text.Font(Kalpurush, 16, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD, color_green);
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int pdfname = rnd.Next(1, 10000);
            FileStream os = new FileStream(@"D:\dlsmpdf\print" + pdfname.ToString() + ".rod", FileMode.Create);

            using (os)
            {
                PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, os);
                    //open the stream 
                    doc.Open();

                    doc.NewPage();
                    doc.SetMargins(20f, 40f, 200f, 100f);

                    // doc.setMargin









                    //  Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 30f, 30f, 42f, 30f);

                    //var output = new FileStream(@"D:\dlsmpdf\print", FileMode.Create);


                    writer.PageEvent = new Header();
                    writer.PageEvent = new Footer();
                    // Open the Document for writing
                    doc.Open();


                    //    PdfContentByte tab = writer.DirectContent;
                    //    PdfPTable tabe = new PdfPTable(4);
                    //    tabe.TotalWidth = 400f;
                    //    //fix the absolute width of the table
                    //    tabe.LockedWidth = true;

                    //    //relative col widths in proportions - 1/3 and 2/3
                    //    float[] widths = new float[] { 100f, 100f, 100f, 100f };
                    //    tabe.SetWidths(widths);
                    //    tabe.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
                    //    //leave a gap before and after the table
                    //    tabe.SpacingBefore = 20f;
                    //    tabe.SpacingAfter = 30f;
                    //PdfPCell:
                    //    cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM party_tin WHERE item = '" + str + "' AND order_no = '" + order + "'", con);
                    //    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    //    reader.Read();

                    //    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Header spanning 3 columns"));
                    //    cell.Colspan = 3;
                    //    cell.HorizontalAlignment = 1; //0=Left, 1=Centre, 2=Right
                    //    tabe.AddCell(cell);
                    //    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Order No:", f_12_normal));
                    //    tabe.AddCell(cell);

                    //    string order1 = reader.GetString("order_no");
                    //    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(order1, f_12_color));

                    //    tabe.AddCell("Col 2 Row 1");
                    //    tabe.AddCell("Col 3 Row 1");
                    //    tabe.AddCell("Col 1 Row 2");
                    //    tabe.AddCell("Col 2 Row 2");
                    //    tabe.AddCell("Col 3 Row 2");
                    //    tabe.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 20, 450, tab);





                    ///////////1st table////////////
                    PdfContentByte ab = writer.DirectContent;
                    PdfPTable able = new PdfPTable(4);
                    float[] width = new float[] { 90f, 180f, 80f, 150f };
                    able.TotalWidth = 500f;
                    con.Open();
                    string Query = "SELECT * FROM party_rod WHERE item = '" + str + "' AND order_no = '" + order + "'";
                    MySqlCommand cmdt = new MySqlCommand(Query, con);
                    MySqlDataReader myReader;
                    myReader = cmdt.ExecuteReader();

                    myReader.Read();
                    PdfPCell ell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Order NO:", f_12_normal));
                    ell.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
                    ell.Border = 0;
                    able.AddCell(ell);


                    string order_no = myReader.GetString("order_no");
                    ell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(order_no));
                    ell.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
                    ell.Border = 0;
                    able.AddCell(ell);

                    ell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Date:", f_12_normal));
                    ell.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
                    ell.Border = 0;
                    able.AddCell(ell);


                    string date = String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", myReader.GetString("order_date"));
                    ell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(date));
                    ell.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
                    ell.Border = 0;
                    able.AddCell(ell);

                    ell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Name:", f_12_normal));
                    ell.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
                    ell.Border = 0;
                    able.AddCell(ell);

                    string name = myReader.GetString("name");
                    ell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(name));
                    ell.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
                    ell.Border = 0;
                    able.AddCell(ell);



                    // 2nd row

                    ell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Address:", f_12_normal));
                    ell.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
                    ell.Border = 0;
                    able.AddCell(ell);

                    string address = myReader.GetString("address");
                    ell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(address));
                    ell.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
                    ell.Border = 0;
                    able.AddCell(ell);

                    ell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Company:", f_12_normal));
                    ell.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
                    ell.Border = 0;
                    able.AddCell(ell);


                    string company = myReader.GetString("mill_name");
                    ell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(company));
                    ell.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
                    ell.Border = 0;
                    able.AddCell(ell);


                    //3rd row

                    ell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Phone No:", f_12_normal));
                    ell.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
                    ell.Border = 0;
                    able.AddCell(ell);

                    string phone = myReader.GetString("phone");
                    ell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(phone));
                    ell.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
                    ell.Border = 0;
                    able.AddCell(ell);


                    ell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Mill Name:", f_12_normal));
                    ell.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
                    ell.Border = 0;
                    able.AddCell(ell);

                    string mill_name = myReader.GetString("mill_name");
                    ell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(mill_name));
                    ell.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
                    ell.Border = 0;
                    able.AddCell(ell);


                    able.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 50, 650, ab);
                    //reader.Close();




                    ////////////2nd table///////////////

                    PdfContentByte tab2 = writer.DirectContent;
                    PdfPTable table2 = new PdfPTable(new float[] { 30f, 30f, 30f, 30f, 30f, 30f, 40f, 40f, 40f, 50f, 50f, 50f });
                    table2.TotalWidth = 540f;
                    //header
                    PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Size", f_12_normal));
                    cell2.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
                    cell2.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(210, 211, 213);
                    table2.AddCell(cell2);

                    cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Ton", f_12_normal));
                    cell2.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
                    cell2.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(210, 211, 213);
                    table2.AddCell(cell2);

                    cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Tk of Ton", f_12_normal));
                    cell2.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
                    cell2.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(210, 211, 213);
                    table2.AddCell(cell2);

                    cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("KG", f_12_normal));
                    cell2.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
                    cell2.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(210, 211, 213);
                    table2.AddCell(cell2);

                    cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Tk of KG", f_12_normal));
                    cell2.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
                    cell2.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(210, 211, 213);
                    table2.AddCell(cell2);

                    cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Gram", f_12_normal));
                    cell2.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
                    cell2.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(210, 211, 213);
                    table2.AddCell(cell2);

                    cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Tk of Gram", f_12_normal));
                    cell2.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
                    cell2.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(210, 211, 213);
                    table2.AddCell(cell2);

                    cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("House Labour Charge", f_12_normal));
                    cell2.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
                    cell2.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(210, 211, 213);
                    table2.AddCell(cell2);

                    cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Mill Labour Charge", f_12_normal));
                    cell2.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
                    cell2.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(210, 211, 213);
                    table2.AddCell(cell2);

                    cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Product Price", f_12_normal));
                    cell2.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
                    cell2.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(210, 211, 213);
                    table2.AddCell(cell2);

                    cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Ex due", f_12_normal));
                    cell2.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
                    cell2.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(210, 211, 213);
                    table2.AddCell(cell2);

                    cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Cash", f_12_normal));
                    cell2.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
                    cell2.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(210, 211, 213);
                    table2.AddCell(cell2);


                    ////rows/////
                    //   con.Open();
                    double total = 0.0;
                    double total_tn = 0.0;
                    double total_tk_of_tn = 0.0;
                    double total_kg = 0.0;
                    double total_gram = 0.0;
                    double total_house = 0.0;
                    double total_ex_due = 0.0;
                    double total_cash = 0.0;
                    double total_due = 0.0;
                    double total_amount = 0.0;
                    con.Close();
                    //double total_amnt = 0.0;
                    DataGridViewRow rw = new DataGridViewRow();
                    for (int i = 0; i < dgv_party_rod.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        rw = dgv_party_rod.Rows[i];
                        if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[0].Value) == true)
                        {
                            con.Open();
                            str = row.Cells["item"].Value.ToString();
                            order = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["order_no"].Value);
                            string Query1 = "select * from party_rod  WHERE item = '" + str + "' AND order_no = '" + order + "'";

                            MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand(Query1, con);
                            MySqlDataReader myReader1;


                            myReader1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

                            myReader1.Read();

                            string size = myReader1.GetString("size");
                            cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(size));
                            cell2.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
                            table2.AddCell(cell2);


                            string acc = myReader1.GetString("ton");
                            cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(acc));
                            cell2.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
                            // cell2.Border = 0;
                            table2.AddCell(cell2);


                            string bank_name = myReader1.GetString("tk_of_ton");
                            cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(bank_name));
                            cell2.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
                            // cell2.Border = 0;
                            table2.AddCell(cell2);

                            string dscrption = myReader1.GetString("kg");
                            cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(dscrption));
                            cell2.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
                            table2.AddCell(cell2);

                            string taka = myReader1.GetString("tk_of_kg");
                            cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(taka));
                            cell2.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
                            table2.AddCell(cell2);

                            string f = myReader1.GetString("gram");
                            cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(f));
                            cell2.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
                            table2.AddCell(cell2);

                            string g = myReader1.GetString("tk_of_gram");
                            cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(g));
                            cell2.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
                            table2.AddCell(cell2);

                            string hlc = myReader1.GetString("house_labour_charge");
                            cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(hlc));
                            cell2.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
                            table2.AddCell(cell2);

                            string mlc = myReader1.GetString("mill_labour_charge");
                            cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(mlc));
                            cell2.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
                            table2.AddCell(cell2);

                            string pp = myReader1.GetString("total_amount");
                            cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(pp));
                            cell2.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
                            table2.AddCell(cell2);

                            string ed = myReader1.GetString("ex_due");
                            cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(ed));
                            cell2.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
                            table2.AddCell(cell2);

                            string cash = myReader1.GetString("cash");
                            cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(cash));
                            cell2.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
                            table2.AddCell(cell2);

                            con.Close();
                        }

                    }


                    ///total row///
                    cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Total:", f_12_normal));
                    cell2.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
                    table2.AddCell(cell2);

                    cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(total_tn.ToString(), f_12_normal));
                    cell2.HorizontalAlignment = 2;
                    table2.AddCell(cell2);

                    cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(total_tk_of_tn.ToString(), f_12_normal));
                    cell2.HorizontalAlignment = 2;
                    table2.AddCell(cell2);


                    cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(total_kg.ToString(), f_12_normal));
                    cell2.HorizontalAlignment = 2;
                    table2.AddCell(cell2);

                    cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(total_gram.ToString(), f_12_normal));
                    cell2.HorizontalAlignment = 2;
                    table2.AddCell(cell2);

                    cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(total_house.ToString(), f_12_normal));
                    cell2.HorizontalAlignment = 2;
                    table2.AddCell(cell2);

                    cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(total.ToString(), f_12_normal));
                    cell2.HorizontalAlignment = 2;
                    table2.AddCell(cell2);

                    cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(total_ex_due.ToString(), f_12_normal));
                    cell2.HorizontalAlignment = 2;
                    table2.AddCell(cell2);

                    cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(total_cash.ToString(), f_12_normal));
                    cell2.HorizontalAlignment = 2;
                    table2.AddCell(cell2);

                    /////total amount///

                    total_due += Convert.ToDouble((total + total_house + total_ex_due) - total_cash);
                    total_amount += Convert.ToDouble((total + total_house + total_ex_due));


                    cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" "));
                    cell2.HorizontalAlignment = 2;
                    cell2.Border = 0;
                    table2.AddCell(cell2);

                    cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" "));
                    cell2.HorizontalAlignment = 2;
                    cell2.Border = 0;
                    table2.AddCell(cell2);

                    cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" "));
                    cell2.HorizontalAlignment = 2;
                    cell2.Border = 0;
                    table2.AddCell(cell2);

                    cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" "));
                    cell2.HorizontalAlignment = 2;
                    cell2.Border = 0;
                    table2.AddCell(cell2);



                    cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" "));
                    cell2.HorizontalAlignment = 2;
                    cell2.Border = 0;
                    table2.AddCell(cell2);



                    cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Total Amount:", f_16_normal));
                    cell2.HorizontalAlignment = 2;
                    cell2.Border = 0;
                    cell2.Colspan = 2;
                    table2.AddCell(cell2);

                    cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(""));
                    cell2.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                    cell2.Border = 0;
                    cell2.Colspan = 2;
                    table2.AddCell(cell2);

                    cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" "));
                    cell2.HorizontalAlignment = 2;
                    cell2.Border = 0;
                    table2.AddCell(cell2);


                    /////total amount///


                    cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" "));
                    cell2.HorizontalAlignment = 2;
                    cell2.Border = 0;
                    table2.AddCell(cell2);

                    cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" "));
                    cell2.HorizontalAlignment = 2;
                    cell2.Border = 0;
                    table2.AddCell(cell2);

                    cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" "));
                    cell2.HorizontalAlignment = 2;
                    cell2.Border = 0;
                    table2.AddCell(cell2);

                    cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" "));
                    cell2.HorizontalAlignment = 2;
                    cell2.Border = 0;
                    table2.AddCell(cell2);


                    cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Total Cash:", f_16_bold_green));
                    cell2.HorizontalAlignment = 2;
                    cell2.Border = 0;
                    cell2.Colspan = 2;
                    table2.AddCell(cell2);

                    cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(""));
                    cell2.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                    cell2.Border = 0;
                    cell2.Colspan = 2;
                    table2.AddCell(cell2);

                    cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" "));
                    cell2.HorizontalAlignment = 2;
                    cell2.Border = 0;
                    table2.AddCell(cell2);

                    /////total amount///


                    cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" "));
                    cell2.HorizontalAlignment = 2;
                    cell2.Border = 0;
                    table2.AddCell(cell2);

                    cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" "));
                    cell2.HorizontalAlignment = 2;
                    cell2.Border = 0;
                    table2.AddCell(cell2);

                    cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" "));
                    cell2.HorizontalAlignment = 2;
                    cell2.Border = 0;
                    table2.AddCell(cell2);

                    cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" "));
                    cell2.HorizontalAlignment = 2;
                    cell2.Border = 0;
                    table2.AddCell(cell2);



                    cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Total Due:", f_16_bold));
                    cell2.HorizontalAlignment = 2;
                    cell2.Border = 0;
                    cell2.Colspan = 2;
                    table2.AddCell(cell2);

                    cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(""));
                    cell2.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                    cell2.Border = 0;
                    cell2.Colspan = 2;
                    table2.AddCell(cell2);

                    cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" "));
                    cell2.HorizontalAlignment = 2;
                    cell2.Border = 0;
                    table2.AddCell(cell2);

                    table2.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 30, 550, tab2);
                    doc.Add(table2);

                    doc.Close();


                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"D:\dlsmpdf\print" + pdfname.ToString() + ".rod");
            }
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("আইটেম সিলেক্ট করুন");
        }
    }
```

please try to help me everyone!
thank you :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is some iText7 code to generate a table that spans multiple pages.
You should be able to combine it with code to insert headers and footers and have a working example for your usecase:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    File file = new File(DEST);
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    new SplitRowAtEndOfPage().manipulatePdf(DEST);
}

@Override
protected void manipulatePdf(String dest) throws Exception {
    Table table = new Table(1);
    table.setWidth(550);
    // the number of iterations has been changed in order to provide the same as in itext5 example
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        Cell cell;
        if (i == 5) {
            cell = new Cell().add("Three\nLines\nHere");
        } else {
            cell = new Cell().add(Integer.toString(i));
        }
        table.addCell(cell);
    }

    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
    Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc, new PageSize(612, 237));
    doc.add(table);
    doc.close();
}
```

Have a look at http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/tables/clone-splitting-tables for more examples.